# Billing field order in checkout page Woocommerce 4

Tags: woocommerce

In WooCommerce 4.2.0, in the checkout page, when I choose Spain, the "state" field is after the zipcode and the city fields:

[image: spain]

but when I choose Ukraine, the the "state" field is after the city field and the zipcode field is after the state field:

[image]

How can I obtain the right order (as for Spain) for all countries with a "state"?

I added this in functions.php, but Ukraine fields order is still wild:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 90, 1 );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

$fields['account']['account_username']['placeholder']   = __( 'Username or email*', 'woocommerce' );
$fields['account']['account_password']['placeholder']   = __( 'Password*', 'woocommerce' );
$fields['account']['account_password-2']['placeholder'] = __( 'Repeat password*', 'woocommerce' );

//set order of billing fields
$order = array(
    "billing_first_name", 
    "billing_last_name", 
    "billing_company", 
    "billing_address_1", 
    "billing_address_2", 
    "billing_postcode",
    "billing_city",
    "billing_state",
    "billing_country", 
    "billing_email", 
    "billing_phone"

);
foreach($order as $field)
{
    $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
}
$fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
```